# How to enable TLS SSL Https in Azure service fabric mesh for Asp.net core application

Tags: azure-service-fabric-mesh

I am deploying a new mesh app with an Asp.Net API core container image. I am able to successfully deploy and access the API using http://[]:80. I used the Following configuration in gateway yaml file:

```
http:
  - name: BenApiHTTP
    port: 80
    hosts:
      - name: "*"
        routes:
          - name: benapi
            match:
              path:
                value: "/benapiservice/"
                rewrite: "/"
                type: Prefix
            destination:
              applicationName: BenApplication
              serviceName: BenApi
              endpointName: BenApiListener
```

Now I want to use my own ssl certificate and wants to enable the same api using  https i.e. on port 443. So my questions are:

1. How to upload the ssl certificate in mesh?
2. What Yaml updates I have to make in gateway.yaml ?
3. How to set the FQDN for the url ?

Comment: Follow github: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/25285